# How to filter a field from a child model which has a foreign key in parent model in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, api, search, filter

I am trying to build an API in drf for listing the different travel packages. I have two models. The package is a parent model and Topactivities is a child model which has a foreign key to the Package model. Now when I hit localhost:8000/api/allpackages api I need to list all the packages which is not a problem. The problem is I want to filter the packages with activities title in the query. For eg: If I do localhost:8000/api/allpackages?activities=trekking, I need to show all the packages which have the activity of trekking. However, activities are not a field in the package. I am trying to use filter backends.

Here are my models:

```
class Package(models.Model):

    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="15% OFF")
    discounted_price = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    savings = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    special_discount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, 1),
                                          (2, 2),
                                          (3, 3),
                                          (4, 4),
                                          (5, 5))
                                 )

    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})
    content =RichTextField()
    highlights = RichTextField()
    itinerary = RichTextField()
    image_1= models.ImageField(blank=True,null = True)
    image_2= models.ImageField(blank=True,null = True)
    image_3= models.ImageField(blank=True,null = True)
    date_created = models.DateField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.package_name

class TopActivities(models.Model):
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='activities')

    # destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                      processors=[ResizeToFill(100, 50)],
                                      format='JPEG',
                                      options={'quality': 60})
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Here are my views:

```
class AllPackageAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['featured', 'special_discount',]
```

Here are my serializers:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    activities = ActivitiesSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'destination', 'package_name', 'duration', 'featured', 'price', 'discount', 'discounted_price',
                            'savings', 'special_discount', 'rating', 'image', 'date_created', 'activities']

class ActivitiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TopActivities
        fields = ['image', 'title', 'description']
```

My urls:

```
path('api/allpackages', views.AllPackageAPIView.as_view(), name='api-allpackages'),
```

APi picture is here:

[Allpackage api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCpI5.jpg)

Comment: You should try overriding the get_queryset() method and access the query parameter via self.request.query_params['your_param_here'].

Comment: Should I do get_queryset() in package serializer because in view  AllPackageAPIView acitivities fileds are not recognized

Comment: Hi Saroj Paudel! This is a bit more complex use case, so I would suggest to get familiar with django-filter (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and write your own filterset. There you can built your filter and lookups just as you like and more flexible as with the shortcut you are currently using.

Comment: Hi Hary!. can we just do it using get_queryset method?? Because i think that would be much easier.